# shadowInactive attribute in ldif file

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldif

I have the following attributes for a specific user:

```
...
objectClass: shadowAccount
shadowLastChange: 1
shadowInactive: 5
shadowMax: 1
```

Since `shadowMax` is set to 1 day, when I try to log in via SSH I get the message saying I should change the password. However, I'm trying to understand what `shadowInactive` will do after 5 days (`shadowInactive: 5`).

Will the user be unable to log in?

Answer (score 1):

The **shadowInactive** attribute contains the number of days the user is allowed to be inactive for before the account is really marked as inactive.